# Is it allowed to have strongly connected components in a graph in CPM/PERT?

Tags: algorithm, graph, cycle, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have read that every non-trivial SCC is a cycle, which means that in a graph used in CPM/PERT method there shouldn't be any, but after I read some other things, I got a little bit confused :( I really need help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PERT charts indicate the partial ordering of the actions one wants to take, so they can't have cycles. If a cycle would be present it would mean that, f.e. you need to start with activity A, then do B, then C, and then A again - this doesn't make sense. Maybe it would be easier to answer if you would provide a link to the content that got you confused.

EDIT (regarding the OP's comment):
Every SCC must contain cycles. Proof sketch: assume that there exists a SCC without a single cycle in a directed graph. Assume that it contains two vertices: A and B. From [the definition of SCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component) there must exist a path from A to B, and from B to A. So, we always can use one of this paths to travel from A to B, and then the other path to get back from B to A (it will be a different path, because we are considering a directed graph), thus forming a cycle. This leads to a contradiction, so you can't have a SCC without cycles. Regarding my answer above, this suggests that PERT charts can't have SCC's either.

Comment: Actually I think I didn't understand what are strongly connected components as I should. I don't know if in a graph which is used in PERT or CPM method can or can't be some strongly connected components.

Comment: A path in a PERT or CPM method is a constraint that you must do tasks early on in the path before tasks later on in the task - you must build the walls of a house before you put the roof on. If you can get from A to B and from B to A then you have a constraint that you must do B before A and a constraint that you must do A before B - perhaps it is raining and the workers refuse to build the walls without a roof to shelter them. Your PERT or CPM program must tell you that the task is impossible due to conflicting constraints.

Comment: Yes, that was exactly my point. It was an indirect proof, and it led to a contradiction.